# How Do I Add A Caption To An Image In A Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have been asked to automatically add a caption (current date and time) to an image as it is selected by the user within a windows 8 App Store application.

I know how to do this in "bog standard windows" having already done it several times, however, I am unsure how this can be achieved in an app store application.

Does anyone have any guidance? As i cannot immediately see a GraphicsHandle or similar.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to modify the image itself, or simply show a caption with it?  The latter you could easily do in XAML with an element that sits on top of the image.  [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) may be helpful you want to modify the image itself.

Comment: In JavaScript, similarly, one could overlay a <canvas> on the image where the canvas has the caption. Or you can draw the image to the canvas itself, then draw the text, so there's only one element. If needs be, that canvas can be saved out to an image file as well.